# How can I uninstall an apache2 module?

Tags: apache2, uninstallation, apache2-module

It looks like I installed the wrong version of the module using `apxs2`.

Once it's disabled (`a2dismod`), how do I remove it so I can install the correct version?

Seems elementary, yet...somehow...I'm finding nothing on Google, IRC, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's so simple nobody has written it down yet. You just remove the .so file from `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`.

And if you want to be thorough, remove anything that might be in: `/usr/share/doc/module-name`

Comment: Mine was at `/var/httpd/modules`

Comment: And mine in `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/` (CentOS 7).

Comment: but that doesn't work as then you get a series of error's for all the places where file location has been mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

For some modules on Ubuntu you can use apt-get.

To find the installed module `sudo dpkg -l | grep apache`.
To remove `sudo apt-get purge {module_name}`.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php7.0  libapache2-mod-php5
```

Answer (score 0):

The apache modules can be found in
/usr/lib64/apache2
or
/usr/lib64/httpd